# disbale sub domain indexing in robots.txt in virtual hosts

Tags: google-search, robots.txt

i am making a subdomain to  be used in my website
*for example:*

example.com - **test**.example.com

but i am using on single robots file because it is a virutal sub domain only

so how in my robots file to enable example.com indexing but disable **test**.example.com at the same time

because when in search i type "contact us" it gives results for example.com/contact-us and **test**.example.com/contact-us

i want only to display example.com results and **don't index** test.example.com in order to disable its appearance in search result

so i removed the links in google search console but i have to edit robots.txt

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate `robots.txt` for your subdomain, `test.example.com`, and it would be like `test.example.com/robots.txt` with content as below.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Make sure you have a separate, normal one for your `example.com/robots.txt` though.